# Should I make `emacs` a symlink or environment variable?

Tags: linux, command-line, environment-variables, symbolic-link

When I `apt-get install emacs` I can just type `emacs` and it launches.

But I decided to replace the apt repository version (23 currently) with the latest stable release (24.3).  Now, I'd still like to be able to type `emacs` from a shell to launch the new version.

What's the right way to do this?  Symlink, alias, environment variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's personal preference, as all three would technically be "right" but I would reccomend a symlink.